# How to receive a message from a Google Cast Receiver on a web-based sender?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to send a message from a Chromecast (receiver) to the web application it's attached to (sender).  [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.CastReceiverContext#sendCustomMessage) implies this is easy enough:

```
const i = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
i.sendCustomMessage('url:x-cast:com.example.app', undefined, 'my data');
```

However, I can't find any documentation on how to actually receive this message on the web app side.  All I can find is this:

> Similarly, receiver applications can keep senders informed about the state of the receiver by sending messages to connected senders. A receiver application can send messages using sendCustomMessage(namespace, senderId, message) on CastReceiverContext. A receiver can send messages to an individual sender, either in response to a received message or due to an application state change. Beyond point-to-point messaging (with a limit of 64kb), a receiver may also broadcast messages to all connected senders.

*Source: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/core_features*

What API am I looking for to actually receive those messages from the "receiver" on the web-based "sender"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that what I needed was on the session:

```
    session.addMessageListener(config.namespace, (namespace, data) => {

    });
```

Comment: i post question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972342/unable-to-receive-messages-from-receiver-side-using-google-chrome-cast-receiver

Comment: can you please check it once.i did't get it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just to contribute: I use this mechanism to send log messages from receiver to sender over a custom namespace to avoid having to open remote web inspector on the receiver for debugging purposes.